# MVC 4 File Upload not working

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4, null, httppostedfilebase

I am trying to simple upload an image but the HttpPostedFileBase in my controller is always remaining null.

Here is the page :

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("AddPicture","Album",FormMethod.Post,new{enctype=  "multipart/form-data" }))
{ %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

<fieldset>
    <legend>PictureModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrivacyTypeID) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownList("PrivacyTypeID", null, new { name = "PrivacyTypeID", title = "Please select privacy type.", id = "PrivacyTypeID" }) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrivacyTypeID) %>
    </div>
    <div>
        Upload Image: <input type="file" name="File1" />
    </div>        
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

And Here is the Controller of the page:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPicture(Guid id, PictureModel model, HttpPostedFileBase File1)
    {
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];
                try
                {
                    Guid albumid = id;

                    if (File1 != null)
                    {
```

.....

Can anyone please guide me what do i have wrong? I tried everything but no results

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
Upload Image: <input type="file" name="File1" id="File1" />
```

And change this:

```
public ActionResult AddPicture(Guid id, PictureModel model, HttpPostedFile File1)
```

Comment: Also, you should be able to work with File1 directly instead of Request.Files[0]. Model binding rocks :)

Comment: yes yes i know i just used it for testing purposes the Request.Files[0].

Comment: Try changing HttpPostedFileBase to HttpPostedFile. See above.

Comment: again nothing still remaining null.

Comment: This always works for me. Did you add id="File1" to the input tag? If so, try naming it something without numbers or special characters.

Comment: I've changed it and named it MyFile instead of File1. Now it's coming a "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note here that might be wrong, or not the correct way to do it :

1. Where is the Guid id in the form it should be set. `Html.Hidden(yourid);` or `Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id);` <-- make sure to set the model before hand on the latter e.g. :

   ```
   public ActionResult Index(){
       PictureModel p = new PictureModel();
       p.id = Guid.NewGuid();
       return View(p);
   }
   ```
2. Use the proper method for dropdownList and your mapping is wrong too here :

The correct way is to use:

```
 DropDownListFor(model => model.PrivacyTypeID, model => model.selectListOfPrivacyTypes, "-- Select Privacy Type --");
```

If you did want to use dropdownlist method then you should have used the name `PictureModel.PrivacyTypeID` instead of `PrivacyTypeID` to let the mapping work properly

I am not sure if it will fix the issue of the filehandling being null but it will definitly be better code.